# How to evaluate a function using ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to evaluate $r$ given by, 
$$r = \frac{35}{\sqrt{(1+Q)}}\frac{\dot y^2}{H \rho^\frac{1}{4}}$$ 
but some equations that I have used in mathematica have a free parameter $Q$, I want to solve $r$ as a function of $Q$ so that in the end I'll plot $r~ \mbox{vs} Q$. As I know ParametricNDSolve can do this since I don't want to change $Q$ at all places everytime, I just want to change the $Q$ in the final expression for $r$, say $r(t,Q) = ~$some expression involving $Q$ indirectly ($\dot y$,$H$,
$\rho$).

But my code just shows an interpolating function, not a number for $r$ given that I have set $Q=1$. I want to plot $r$ vs. $Q$ for a lot of numbers
My final expression for $r$ involves different parameters.

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18 ;(* Reduced Planck mass = 2.4353*10^18 GeV *)
m = 1.8*10^13 ;(* Inflaton mass = 1.8*10^13 GeV *)
Rm = (1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18); (* Rescaled inflaton mass *)
tfin = 10^7;
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{dy'[t] + 3 H[t] (1 + Q) dy[t] + Rm^2 y[t] == 0, 
                        H[t] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + 0.5 Rm^2 y[t]^2 + ρ[t])/3], 
                        ρ'[t] + 4 H[t] ρ[t] == 3 H[t] Q dy[t]^2, y'[t] == dy[t], 
                        y[0] == -12, dy[0] == 0.0000357, ρ[0] == Rm^4}, 
                        {y, dy, H, ρ}, {t, 0,tfin},{Q}];

ysol[t_, Q_] := y[t] /. sol;
ypsol[t_, Q_] := dy[t] /. sol;
Hsol[t_, Q_] := H[t] /. sol;
ρsol[t_, Q_] := ρ[t] /. sol;

r[t_, Q_] := 35 ypsol[t, Q]^2/(1+Q)^1/2 Hsol[t, Q] ρsol[t, Q]^(1/4)
Evaluate[r[t, 1]] /. {t -> 10^6}
```

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal My final expression involves different variables, the thread that you shown just wants to plot a dependent variable vs some parameter, my dependent variable is a function of several variables, $\dot y$, $H$, $\rho$.

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal Your suggestion was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate form for the `SetDelay` is,

```
ysol[Q_] := y[Q][t] /. sol;
ypsol[Q_] := dy[Q][t] /. sol;
Hsol[Q_] := H[Q][t] /. sol;
ρsol[Q_] := ρ[Q][t] /. sol;    
r[Q_] := 35 ypsol[Q]^2/(1 + Q)^1/2 Hsol[Q] ρsol[Q]^(1/4);
Evaluate[r[1] /. t -> 10^6]
Plot[Evaluate[r[Q] /. t -> 10^6], {Q, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]